How can I create a multipage landscape table in tabularray?
I have tried severall combinations of tblr, longtblr, talltblr, sidewaystable, and landscape but I can't manage to produce a landscape table that spans several pages.

I would also like to repeat the first row of the table in each page.

What is the difference between longtblr and talltblr? It is not described in the documentation.

Can I use booktabs inside a longtblr environment?
Many thanks!


\begin{landscape}
 %\centering
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Research question and main findings},
  label = {tablitrev1},
]{
  %width = \linewidth,
  colspec = {X[l]X[l]X[l]X[l]},      
  % colspec = {Q[65]Q[208]Q[262]Q[404]},
  rowhead = 1,
  cells = {t}
  hline{1,2,43} = {-}{0.08em},
}
%\toprule
\textbf{Article} & \textbf{Keywords} & \textbf{Research question} & \textbf{Main findings}\\
%\midrule
\textcite{li2001} & NA & Lorem ipsum\\
\textcite{wang2002} & error-correction
  model; forecasting & lorem ipsum 2\\
  %\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{landscape}

\begin{landscape}
 %\centering
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Research question and main findings},
  label = {tablitrev1},
]{
  %width = \linewidth,
  colspec = {X[l]X[l]X[l]X[l]},      
  % colspec = {Q[65]Q[208]Q[262]Q[404]},
  rowhead = 1,
  cells = {t}
  hline{1,2,43} = {-}{0.08em},
}
%\toprule
\textbf{Article} & \textbf{Keywords} & \textbf{Research question} & \textbf{Main findings}\\
%\midrule
\textcite{li2001} & NA & Lorem ipsum & finding 1\\
\textcite{wang2002} & error-correction
  model; forecasting & lorem ipsum 2 & finding 2\\
  %\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{landscape}


Some demonstration of code, even one that does not produce the desired result, would be beneficial to this question.

Done, thanks por pointing it out!

I'm getting errors which have nothing to do with landscape (since I tried commenting them out).  Other than that, it works.


Meanwhile longtblr can be multipage long and can be broke between pages, talltblr can be used in table in table environment and should be used for table which can be fit in one page.
This are quite clearly explained in package documentation, however its fiven more intention to longtblr tabler. Bot have equal syntaxt with differencve that talltblr not suport repeating column headers on each pages and notes for continuation of table on the next page (since it doersn't need this).
Your MWE is close to what you after (if you realy need a long table). I extend xour MWE so, that it can demostrate behaviour of longtblr:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage[font=small,
            labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tblr-extras}        %%%% new   
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, 
                caption}        %%%% new, caption style is determined bx `caption` package

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Research question and main findings},
  label = {tablitrev1},
                ]{colspec = {Q[l] X[l]X[2,l]X[2,l]},      
                  row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
                  rowhead = 1, % repeat first table row on each page
                  }
    \toprule
Article         &   Keywords    &   Research question   
                                    &   Main findings       \\
    \midrule
\cite{li2001}   & NA & Lorem ipsum\\
\cite{wang2002} & error-correction model; forecasting         
                                &   \lipsum[66]       
                                    &   \lipsum[66]         \\
\cite{wang2002} & error-correction model; forecasting         
                                &   \lipsum[11]       
                                    &   \lipsum[66]         \\
\cite{wang2002} & error-correction model; forecasting         
                                &   \lipsum[11]       
                                    &   \lipsum[66]         \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
  % colspec = {Q[65]Q[208]Q[262]Q[404]},
\end{document}

Just for demostration purposes I change a bit your table layout and use ˙lipsum   package for cell filling with dummy text. You can can change table design as you wish.


This is a great answer. Could you explain the meaning of colspec = {Q[l] X[l]X[2,l]X[2,l]}, please? What is Q? what do you add a 2 in the X columns? thank you.

@SparklingWater, the best explanation about column explanation you can find in tabularray package documentation. Shortly; Q is column type to which you can add option for cell text align, fot stypes and shapes etc. which has natural width of cells (i.e. depend on  bigest text width in cells) or  prescribed  width. X column is extension of X columns known from tabularx package which enable to set cells width.

I've got two questions please, 1. tblr-extras is only used to control the caption? and, 2. in X[2,l] 2 are the inches of the column?

@SparklingWater, tblr-extras is for formating of caption by means of caption package, in X[2,l]  the number 2 is ratio between columns widths: means that this column has width twice of X column. Please, see package documentation where this is thorouglhtly explained.
